# Объявление функции-конструктора без присвоения переменной. Как найти объект функции с последующим удалением?

Tags: javascript

Итак есть код js:

```
var classlist = [];

function MyClass() {
 var self = this;
}

if (true) {
 classlist.push(new MyClass());
}
```

И теперь вопросы:

1. Создан объект и он добавлен в массив, если я удалю массив объект останется, но как получить к нему доступ?
2. Как получить все созданные объекты одного класса, к примеру MyClass?
3. Как полностью удалить такой объект из памяти?

Comment: останется объект или нет будет решать GC

Answer (score 2):

В Javascript нет инструментов для прямой работы с памятью, поэтому нельзя сказать останется ли объект после удаления всех ссылок на него или нет, и если останется то на сколько долго. Это зависит от конкретной реализации движка и его сборщика мусора.

В любом случае, при отсутствии ссылок на объект из кода к нему никак нельзя будет обратиться.

---

Для получения всех созданных объектов одного класса их, нужно вручную где-то сохранить при создании, например в отдельном массиве.

Автоматически список созданных объектов не ведется.